# Vagrant not looking for puppet manifest in the right place

Tags: settings, puppet, vagrant

I'm trying to use provision vagrant using puppet

My Vagrantfile is like this

```
Vagrant::Config.run  do |config|
    config.vm.box = "precise32"
    config.vm.provision :puppet  do |puppet|
       puppet.modules_path = "/path/to/puppet/modules"
       puppet.manifest_path = "/path/to/puppet/manifests"
       puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp"
       puppet.puppet_node = "lucy-dev-1"
       ## custom facts provided to Puppet
       puppet.facter = {
          ## tells default.pp that we're running in Vagrant
          "is_vagrant" => true,
       }
       puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
    end
 end
```

When I run `vagrant up` the following error happen:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

puppet provisioner:
   * The manifests path specified for Puppet does not exist: /Users/fguimara/vagrant/manifests
```

You can notice that the manifest_path is not being respected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html it's `manifests_path`.